Can you have more infusions active than your daily limit?
I am a 3rd-level artificer. I know the infusions Enhanced Defence, Repeating Shot, Enhanced Weapon, and Replicate Magic Item (Bag of Holding).
If I infuse a suit of armor (with Enhanced Defence) and a crossbow (with Repeating Shot) one day, take a long rest, and then use my other two infusions the next day, do the items from the first day lose their infusions?

Yes, the older effects end. From the description of the ability:

Infuse Item
You can infuse more than one nonmagical object at the end of a long rest; the maximum number of objects appears in the Infused Items column of the Artificer table. You must touch each of the objects, and each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time. Moreover, no object can bear more than one of your infusions at a time. If you try to exceed your maximum number of infusions, the oldest infusion ends, and then the new infusion applies.

So, as soon as you infuse the bag or dagger, the first infusion from the previous day ends.
